# Select Element in Outliner "File Mode" based on Object Name

Tags: scripting, development

**I've added an EDIT at the Bottom.**

I want to select the corresponding element in the "File View" Outliner Mode to the active Object in the scene context. Is this possible? I know its possible to select an item in the regular outliner, but i could not get it to work for the File Mode.

[image]

```
import bpy

active_object = bpy.context.active_object

if bpy.context.area.type!='OUTLINER':
    #If needed find the outliner area
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'OUTLINER':
            areaOverride=area
            
with bpy.context.temp_override(area=areaOverride):
    
    bpy.ops.outliner.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    
    bpy.ops.outliner.select_item(name=active_object, extend=True)
```

The Last line in this code example is what i'm sadly struggling with and not finding a solution as to how i would correctly set the item as active. Does anyone have an idea how a correct method would look like?

**EDIT:**
With the answer of Yaroslav i was enable to narrow down some options, the following code filters the outliner for the asset name (could be an object, library and many more) After the filtering the only step missing is to "activate" this single visible element and run the Relocate Operator. However, when "Toggling" the selection, every element gets selected, not just the visible one which results in the first linked path to be opened by the relocating operator - not the one we want. But, after the Relocating Window Popup, if the script is run again, it now uses the correct one. Is there maybe a selection/active update in the background after a window is closed?

```
asset_name = "American_hornbeam.blend"

if bpy.context.area.type!='OUTLINER':
    #If needed find the outliner area
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'OUTLINER':
            areaOverride=area
            
with bpy.context.temp_override(area=areaOverride):

    bpy.context.space_data.display_mode = 'LIBRARIES'   ## switch Outliner to 'Blender File'
    bpy.context.space_data.use_filter_id_type = True   ## enable filter
    bpy.context.space_data.filter_id_type = 'OBJECT'   ## filter by type 'Object' / can be changed to Library as well
    bpy.context.space_data.filter_text = asset_name   ## search for the object's name, could be the path as well  
    bpy.ops.outliner.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    bpy.ops.outliner.select_all(action='TOGGLE')
    bpy.ops.outliner.lib_operation(type='RELOCATE')
```

Comment: I could help you, but for now your additional questions are kind of cryptic. I need more details about what exactly you want to do next (after my script is executed), and what specifically are you planning to achieve (answer below my post - so I will be notified about your messages)

Comment: I've updated my answer. If my updated solution is ok for you – mark my post as "accepted"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the new information you've provided – I've enhanced the code's functionality.

(!) Note:

I've encountered a Blender's unexpected behavior. Because of that (as a workaround) there are two scripts. They should be kept separately and should be launched consequentially.

–––

The first script finds the active object in the Blend File – it's name is  "1 _find_in_outliner.py"

The second one relocates the linked library  – it's name  is "2_relocate_library.py"

HERE:

---

**{1 _find_in_outliner.py} :**

```
import bpy


active_object = bpy.context.active_object
 
outliner = [a for a in bpy.context.screen.areas if (a.type == 'OUTLINER')][0]
     
       
               
with bpy.context.temp_override(area=outliner):
    
    bpy.context.space_data.display_mode = 'LIBRARIES'   ## switch Outliner to 'Blender File'
 
    bpy.context.space_data.use_filter_id_type = True   ## enable filter
        
    bpy.context.space_data.filter_id_type = 'OBJECT'   ## filter by type 'Object'
    
    bpy.context.space_data.filter_text = active_object.name   ## search for the object's name
```

---

**{2_relocate_library.py} :**

```
import bpy


active_object = bpy.context.active_object
 
outliner = [a for a in bpy.context.screen.areas if (a.type == 'OUTLINER')][0]
     
       
               
with bpy.context.temp_override(area=outliner):
    
    bpy.ops.outliner.select_all(True)
    
    bpy.ops.outliner.lib_operation(type='RELOCATE')
```

Comment: Thank you! This is part of the way there to what i need i think. It's selecting something in the right context, smart using the filter! Do you think it would be possible to set the "owner" of the asset as active/selected? For linke objects it looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/3Een6oN I need to run an operator once the "parent" of the object is selected/active

Comment: So what i'm trying to do is add a button to the "Object">"Instancing" Panel that lets me relocate its source file. Usually we need to go to the outliner, switch to file mode, then right click on the path/file and click relocate. The bpy.ops.outliner.lib_operation(type='RELOCATE') needs to be run from the outliner context as far as i'm aware, it also uses the "active" element as to what gets its source relocated. Sorry if i was a bit cryptic, i'm learning so much here and couldn't really phrase it before.